# Responsive Font Size and Controls on WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have some questions about *Responsive Desing* on **WPF**.

The first:

I have a control inside a row of the grid; the program runs full screen, therefore, control is very small, as in the image:
[image]

The DatePicker is inside of a ViewBox to make responsive, but the control does not cover the entire space of the row.

**What should I do to cover all the space?**

This is my XAML code:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="4" Margin="0 1">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
         </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Viewbox Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
          <Label Background="Gainsboro" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Content="Fecha de Nacimiento:" />
     </Viewbox>
     <Viewbox Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
          <DatePicker Grid.Column="1" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
     </Viewbox>
</Grid>
```

My second question is:

I have a DataGrid filled with information that I get from a query to a REST service. It also runs full-screen, the question is:

**What I can do to make all text responsive in the DataGrid?**

This is my XAML code:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dtgClientes" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding lstClientes}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectionMode="Single" SelectionUnit="FullRow" AlternatingRowBackground="WhiteSmoke" IsReadOnly="True" RowHeaderWidth="0">
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#066DCC"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.Resources>
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Binding="{Binding Persona.Nombre}">
        <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
            <TextBlock Text="Nombre" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
        </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
    </DataGridTextColumn>
    <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Binding="{Binding Persona.ApellidoPaterno}">
        <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
            <TextBlock Text="Apellido Paterno" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
        </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
    </DataGridTextColumn>
    <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Binding="{Binding Persona.ApellidoMaterno}">
        <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
            <TextBlock Text="Apellido materno" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
        </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
    </DataGridTextColumn>
    <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Binding="{Binding Persona.Telefono}">
        <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
            <TextBlock Text="Teléfono" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
        </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
    </DataGridTextColumn>
    <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Binding="{Binding Persona.TelefonoMovil}">
        <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
            <TextBlock Text="Móvil" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
        </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
    </DataGridTextColumn>
    <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Binding="{Binding Persona.Domicilio}">
        <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
            <TextBlock Text="Domicilio" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
        </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
    </DataGridTextColumn>
    <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Binding="{Binding Persona.FechaNacimiento}">
        <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
            <TextBlock Text="Fecha de Nacimiento" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
        </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
    </DataGridTextColumn>
    <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Binding="{Binding Persona.Rfc}">
        <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
            <TextBlock Text="RFC" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
        </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
    </DataGridTextColumn>
    <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Binding="{Binding Persona.Curp}">
        <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
            <TextBlock Text="CURP" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
        </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
    </DataGridTextColumn>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

Comment: First question: your grid is inside another grid, and you want to make it fill the entire width of the row it is in. That is my understanding. There are lots of options. You could use a horizontal stackpanel rather than a grid, for example. You could define bind the width of your grid to the width of row4.

Comment: I used the StackPanel but did not work

Comment: I have just played around a bit, and I think the `ViewBox`is the problem. The default `Stretch`is `Uniform`. The `DatePicker`is stretched uniformly in both directions, but it stops before it goes outside the row of your outer `Grid`. You could set the stretch to `Fill`, but the result is not going to be what you want. I'm not quite sure what you do want, so don't know what to suggest.